# how to deal with search box result?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
    'q': '10000'
    }

r = requests.get('https://beta.tamilnadumedicalcouncil.org/info/doctors/search',data = payload 
,headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
products = soup.find('td', {'class':'ant-descriptions-item-content'})
print(products)
```

Trying to get data by putting  values in the search box but it is not giving the result.Tried to use payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `'Authorization' HTTP header to obtain the information.

For example:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://beta.tamilnadumedicalcouncil.org/server/api/rmp/search'
payload = {
    'params': r'{}',
    'q': 10000
}
headers = {'Authorization': r'Bearer {}'}

data = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['payload'][0]['fullName'], data['payload'][0]['qualification'])
```

Prints:

```
Taylor  Ronald Yeldham Major I M S I A M C L.L.M.R.C.S
```